# How to save self tracking entities in entity framework?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, self-tracking-entities

[image: My Database Tables and thier relationship]

This is my database structure I have four tables. Table  **LocalArea and Lanungaue** have master data and which refered by the tables **Address and AddressTranslated**

Now I want to add rows in **Address and AddressTranslated** table  I used following code store **Address** table row

```
Address.localarea = new localarea() { LocalAreaID = 1 };

        using (var context = new en_Entities())
        {

            context.Address.Attach(Address);
            context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(Address.LocalArea, EntityState.Unchanged);
            context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(Address, EntityState.Added);

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

The code working fine and adds row in Address table.

How do i add row in  **AddressTranslated** ?? what changes/line of code do i need to add data in AddressTranslate table.

Comment: +1 for the whiteboard picture :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My **AddressTranslated table was not having any primary key column** thats why couldnt add row to childtable.

**After adding a primary key column all records got saved to DB.**